# How to handle weak and strong pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In my Application I enable ARC and and also new to it. I got into some trouble because of the inexperienced Handling of the ARC enabled code

I have a strong property named `data` of type `NSMutableArray` and a weak instance variable `_currentData` of the same type

I use the `_currentData` to load tableView in the application . The main collection which I want to display is always in `data` variable. I point the MutableArray pointed by `data` variable by `_currentData` variable and below is my ViewDidLoad

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
    data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //load the data 

    _currentData=data; 
    [myTableView reloadData];

}
```

and my dataSource method is like below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [_currentData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     id var=[_currentData objectAtInsex:indexPath.row];
     //.....my drawing methods on the cell View 
     return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id var=[_currentData objectAtInsex:indexPath.row];
    NSlog(@"var %@",var);
}
```

the above code is working fine and every time when i tap the cell I got the var printed
until I plan to implement a search bar as in the below code

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    _currentData =[data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name contains[c] '%@'",searchText]]];//  Object with attribute name
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

the above code is working fine upto showing the filtered results in tableView but i got null printed when i tap any of the row

I don't know to where it went wrong.

Comment: `_currentData =[data filterUsingPredicate:myPredicateVariable];` how does this compile? Is this your actual code? And why is `_currentData` weak?

Comment: how can you say it works when it doesn't compile? .. i mean you assign void to an id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `currentData` be weak works when it's simply pointing at `data`. As long as `data` is around, `currentData` will be kept and when `data` goes away, so will `currentData`.

Your problem is that you assign `currentData` to a new value:

```
_currentData =[data filterUsingPredicate:myPredicateVariable];
```

or *would have* if `filterUsingPredicate:` returned a value (I think you meant `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`) which would only be in scope until the end of the method. By the time `reloadData` gets called, `currentData` has been released. You either need to assign `[data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicateVariable];` to a strong property or ivar, or declare `currentData` as strong.

Comment: `filterUsingPredicate` is from NSMutableArray and void you mean arrayByFilteringUsingPredicate`

Comment: this isn't the problem as the code doesn't even compile that way ^^

Comment: @Daij-Djan What's with the downvote? I copied and pasted his code from his example. His question was about ARC and strong/weak pointers, which I answered. My answer explains the ARC mechanics which is what he was interested in.

Comment: no you explicitly say that the assign in the line that doesn't compile is his problem, leading onto a false trail. fix it = no down vote :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan data is a property with strong attribute in the .m file

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText  {   
    _currentData =[data filterUsingPredicate:myPredicateVariable];
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

there is fault logic here. You filter array (in-place) as you modify the mutable array. **What you want is to get a NEW filtered array** else this works only once/rarely

so

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText  {   
    NSMutableArray *newData = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicateVariable];
    _currentData = newData;
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

THEN **_currentData most be strong** because nobody else is retaining the new array. If it were __weak, it would turn to nil as soon as newData is released